# Unable to get all ID values in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having one page which displays data from the server and I'm adding one button dynamically.

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-li-icon" id="feat" >
</ul>
```

And my JS code is

```
$.each(response.mname, function (i, mname) {

    $('#feat').append(
    '<li>'+ '<a>'+
    '<h4>'+'<p id=name>'+ mname.Name +'</p>' +'</h4>'+
    '<input type="button" value="infobutton" background-color="green" id="button" >'+'</input>'+
    '</a>' +'</li>');

    $("#button").click(function(){
       var m=$("#name").text();
       alert(m);
    });   
});
```

The output shows the data a supposed to:

```
nameabc
infobutton
namexyz
infobutton
```

The problem is: I can click on only the first button and I'm getting the value of `m` only for the  first button but not for all other buttons. When I click on infobutton below of nameabc I'm getting the right value as nameabc. But when I click on infobutton below of namexyz, it's not showing any value.

Comment: IDs must be **unique**! and you can't trigger click for appended elements directly you need event delegation! But i suggest you to write click event outside `.each`  loop!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak They don't **need** event delegation, since they're binding the event handler after appending the new content. It would make the code a lot cleaner to use event delegation, though.

Comment: try `$(".button").on('click', function(){ $(this).closest('li').find('p').text(); });`

Comment: @DhavalMarthak..i tried writting click event outside of forloop but its showing value for that first button only.whatever next buttons are there i m not getting value for that.n then how can i create unique id dynamically for this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$.each(response.mname, function (i, mname) {
    $('#feat').append(
        '<li>' + '<a>' +
        '<h4>' + '<p id=name' + i +'>' + mname.Name + '</p>' + '</h4>' +
        '<input type="button" value="infobutton" background-color="green" id="button' + i +'" >' + '</input>' +
        '</a>' + '</li>');
});
    $("input[id^=button]").click(function () {
        var p = $(this).closest('li').find('p[id^=name]').prop('id').replace(/name/, '');
        alert(p);
    });
```

Comment: can i make this mname.Name invisible?

Comment: if you want to hide from user, then try using <input type='hidden'/>, and according update the script, from `p[id^=name]` to `input[id^=name]`

Comment: okk thanks.but one que if suppose id=name contains integer value then how can i display that value.if its string then.text() is working but for integer value its not showing any value.